# Adding a cylinder to a joint in Maya

Tags: python, maya

I think this is just a declaration issue. I want to constraint one cylinder between 2 joints. This code of block works, it adds a constraint with the weight of 0.5 to every cylinder from all joints. I want to add the constraints in this matter:
cylinder 1 from joint 1 and 2
cylinder 2 from joint 2 and 3
cylinder 3 from joint 3 and 4

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import math as mt

# CREATE THE CYLINDER ON JOINTS
cmds.joint (p = (-5, 0, 0))
cmds.joint (p = (-2, 0, -2))
cmds.joint (p = (10, 0, -6))
cmds.joint (p = (10, 0, 3))
# GET THE RELATIVES FOR THE JOINT CHAIN
sel = cmds.ls (selection = True)
jnt_Hi = cmds.listRelatives (sel, allDescendents = True)
jnt_Hi.extend (sel)

for jnt in jnt_Hi:
    pc = cmds.polyCylinder (name = (jnt + '_cyl'), radius = 1, height = 2, subdivisionsX 
    = 20, subdivisionsY = 1,subdivisionsZ = 1, axis = (0, 1, 0), rcp = 0, createUVs = 3, 
    constructionHistory = 1)
     # CONSTRAINT THE CYLINDER TO THE JOINT
    cmds.pointConstraint (jnt_Hi, pc,
                          weight = 0.5,
                          name = (jnt[0] + 'point_1'))
    cmds.pointConstraint (jnt_Hi, pc,
                          weight = 0.5,
                          name = (jnt[0] + 'point_2'))
```

Comment: I could not find the place where you define _jnt_Hi_.

Comment: Lol.. That part would of helped a lot. Thanks for pointing that out I have adjusted the code and added that piece of code in there.

Answer (score 1):

In the loop:

```
for jnt in jnt_Hi:
```

You iterate over the joint names. But later you reference the joint names as jnt[0] and later j1[0] and j2[0]. Since jnt, j1 and j2 are strings not string arrays, you always get the very first letter in your case "j" what does not exist.

Comment: That is my question. How do I make them string arrays? How can I iterate through joints and get the actual joint and not the name of the joint.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by iterating over joins. From the cmds.ls() you receive a list of joint names and in your loop you iterate over the names and do what you need to do. Just remove the [] brackets, that's all. All maya.cmds commands use strings to identify objects in the scene to work on. If you really want to use a more pythonic approach with objects, you can use pymel which works on objects, not on strings.

Comment: I readjusted the code and gave an explanation to what I would like to do. Please have a look again.

Comment: Now you are not using the joint "jnt" but the array "jnt_Hi" in the constraint command. If you change that the cylinders are placed at the correct position.

Comment: The correct position would be in between two joints, with the weight of 0.5 from each joint. And that's where I keep getting stuck. At constraining one cylinder to two joints. How would you do it? How would you constrain one cylinder to two joints, with code?

Comment: Since you know the positions our you can query the position, why not simply use the average of two joints?

Comment: I did not think of that. And would that not cause the same issue as before? Being able to iterate between the joints in the loop? I guess I can constrain the cylinder after, to just one joint compared to two. The cylinder needs to travel with the joint in space

Comment: Of course you can constraint one cylinder to two joints at the same time. There is no limit as much as I know. Just use an array of two joints as first argument for the pointConstraint() command.